# Using Foundation Orbit Alongside Interchange - Reflow issues

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I am not able to get orbit to trigger its natural behaviour as a slider, when interchange has done its job.

JS:

```
    $(document).foundation('interchange', {
        named_queries : {
            small_range : 'only screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width: 768px)',
            medium_range : 'only screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width: 1024px)',
            large_range : 'only screen and (min-width:1025px) and (max-width: 1200px)',
            xlarge_range : 'only screen and (min-width:1201px)',
        }
    });
```

I have interchange running on another part of site and all works fine there. I need to add obit reflow to the code above with breaking the current interchange html Orbit settings use the data attr).

I have tried:

```
$(document).foundation('interchange', 'orbit', 'reflow', {
```

But to no avail. To clarify Interchange works fine across the site, however when the DOM gets changed the slider behaviour is not triggered..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually fixed my issue. I was using interchange insert an html file with an orbit slider for medium and large screens, but a different file without a slider for small screens. The orbit slider would not work at all after the interchange since the foundation js already fired after the slider was loaded. I fixed it by including this IN the html file i was including that had the orbit slider in order to re-call the js for the slider.

```
<script src="../js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation('orbit', {
  timer_speed: 10000,
  animation_speed: 500,
  bullets: true,
  stack_on_small: true
});
```

by including the 'orbit' call it reloaded the slider and fixed it after the interchange. is that your issue?

Comment: Yeah it did. However I have no idea why foundation can be in a document load. As I have a similar script for interchange ..('interchange'){} but thats another question.. Thanks bud!

Comment: I believe since you have the $(document).foundation(); script in the html, that script runs to call the interchanged document (html file). But you need another one to run with the 'orbit' after the interchange so it will run again for orbit. You probalby don't need the .js files to be reloaded. I think it will work if you just ad this: 

<script>
      $(document).foundation('orbit', {
  timer_speed: 10000,
  animation_speed: 500,
  bullets: true,
  stack_on_small: true
});</script>

Comment: I think I will just add the foundation script inside the document, It funny I don't get of these issues using other frameworks like bootstrap. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently, so after many tests this worked for me :

Added all sliders format in assets/partials ex: slide.html, large-slider.html etc..
Added the interchange plugin and a new data-orbit-interchange attribute
Watch for 'replaced-zf-interchange' event on [data-orbit-interchange]
Get an image from the slide freshly loaded and wait for image loading
Then init the plugins agains

a quick exemple :

html :

```
<div class="widget large-9 medium-8" data-orbit-interchange data-interchange="[assets/partials/sliders/home-slider.html, small],[assets/partials/sliders/home-slider-large.html, large]"></div>
```

javascript :

```
$('[data-orbit-interchange]').on('replaced.zf.interchange', function () {

        var element = $(this).find('.orbit').first();

        var img = $(element).find('.orbit-image').first();

        img.on('load', function() {

            element.foundation();

        });

 });
```

this is not the best solution i guess , but it worked for me,

Hope this can help